# Devexpress : set column and row count to integer value

Tags: c#, devexpress, syncfusion

basically want to set the column count and row count equal to 1 using devexpress.

```
//int startcolumn= 1;
 //int startrow = 1;
//GridControl gd = new Gridcontrol();
//somefunction()
    //{
    //gd.colcount = startcolumn; //colcount & rowcount is a syncfusion type 
    //gd.rowcount = stratrow;
//}
```

how to achieve it in devexpress, please help,  any similar property like colcount in devexpress or any other  way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

`GridControl` is not a matrix-editor. GridControl is a control for showing data. You can't just set number of columns and rows.

You can dynamically [add new column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q279957):

```
DataColumn col = jobTable.Columns.Add("columnKey", typeof(string));
GridColumn column = gridViewJob.Columns.AddVisible(col.ColumnName)
column.Caption = col.Caption;
column.Name = col.ColumnName;
```

and [add new row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q514719).